# Run the application automatically when double click the folder that contains it

Tags: c#

In C# how can I run my app automatically when I double click on the folder that contains this app. So I mean can I catch the double click on local folder event?

Comment: This sounds dodgy as. I hope it isn't possible.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - I completely agree, and as far as I know, it isn't possible without some serious overhead.

Comment: Unless that folder is the root of a CDROM drive, you're out of luck (which is a Good Thing™).

Comment: thanks #yms. This is what I want to find out. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and in particular the notification [NotifyFilters.LastAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Disclaimer: I have not tested this, I do not know if this is going to work for you, since you will (or might?) be notified after the folder has been accessed.

For anything more advanced than this, you will probably need to get your hands dirty with some C++ and implement a [File System Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx), similar to what an anti-virus does.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: **No**. no you can not do that.

Comment: I think I can do that with an autorun.inf file. may be :D

Answer (score 0):

In c# the answer is No. You can do that only if you make your own kind of windows explorer and use that to access there by using a treeview and listview.

Comment: Thank for your help @Kubi. With this idea I just want to show a message to warning user like that "This folder contains important files", ...etc.